# Can't find elements in Elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
res = requests.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/" + "Water" + "/cids/XML")
tree = ET.fromstring(res.content)
CID = tree.find("CID").text
```

The XML present in res is:

```
<IdentifierList xmlns="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest/pug_rest.xsd">
<CID>962</CID>
</IdentifierList>
```

What I would like to retrieve is `962`.

`tree.getchildren()` results in `[<Element '{http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest}CID' at 0x0000024606B9A098>]`. Why does this break, and what do I need to do to fix this? I know that regular expression get easily get me what I need, but I want to perform this with ET (if at all possible of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
res = requests.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/" + "Water" + "/cids/XML")
tree = ET.fromstring(res.content)
CID = tree[0].text
```